# Perl - Can't Call new Method

Tags: perl, oop

I have been working on a small project and I decided to try and use [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures) because I find it neater.

This is without using `Method::Signatures` and it works, I'm able to use the package and call methods.

```
sub new {
    my $self = {};
    bless($self);
    shift;
    $self->{parent} = shift;
    return $self;
}
```

But when I try this, it doesn't work:

```
 method new($parent) {
   bless {}, $self;
   $self->{parent} = $parent;
   return $self;
 }
```

I get an error saying: "Can't use string ("PackageName") as hashref while strict refs in use".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method::Signatures automatically shifts the first argument off the argument list and puts it in `$self` for you. When you call an object method like `$obj->foo`, then `$self` is just `$obj`. But when you call a class method like `Class->method`, then `$self` will be the string `Class`.

Your `$self` contains the string `PackageName`, as it should since you're using `new` as a class method. Then you use `PackageName` as an argument to `bless`, but *throw away the result!*

```
bless {}, $self;
```

This blesses a new empty hashref (the `{ }` ) into the package name contained in `$self` and then throws the result away. You're then trying to use `$self` as a hashref when it's just a string, which is causing the error. So try this:

```
method new($parent) {
   my $obj = bless {}, $self;
   $obj->{parent} = $parent;
   return $obj;
}
```

Comment: [You can change the variable name of the invocant](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures#Invocant-parameter) (ie. $self) with `method new($class: $parent)`, makes it easier to read.

Comment: I think this is a very well explained answer.  I think the OP should accept this as the answer.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
method new($parent) {
   my $instance = bless {} => $self;
   $instance->{parent} = $parent;
   return $instance;
 }
```

In this case, `$self` in your `new` method will the package name. You then bless an empty anonymous hash into that package which gives you your instantiated object.

Incidentally, you should re-write your plain `new` method:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless {} => $class;
    $self->{parent} = shift;
    return $self;
}
```