# Using Perl's Method::Signatures, why can't I invoke methods on an object instance?

Tags: perl, oop

I followed what [friedo said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521717/perl-cant-call-new-method).

Now, when I try to call the method `testScript` I get the error `global symbol $obj requires explicit package name` and it fails to call `testScriptTwo`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Test;

use Method::Signatures;

method new {
    my $obj = bless {}, $self;
    return $obj;
}

method testScript {
       $obj->testScriptTwo(); # Error happens here
}

method testScriptTwo { ... }
```

Test script:

```
use Test;

my $class = Test->new();
$class->testScript();
```

How do I make use of $obj to call methods within the package itself?

Comment: This is why it was important for you to understand the correction I made to your non-Method-Signatures code in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28521819/100754).

Comment: That I understand, but I don't understand the Method::Signatures way. I'm returning $obj and creating references using $obj i.e: $obj->{parent}, why cant I use $obj to call other methods and access those references within the package? But I can while calling new()?

Comment: "why cant I use $obj to call other methods ... But I can while calling new()?" ... Because, you do not understand the lexical scope created by a subroutine definition. The lexical variable `$obj` in `new` and the global variable `$new` you attempted to use in `testScript` have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I think you mean `the global variable $obj`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
method testScript {
       $self->testScriptTwo();
}
```

The first argument is in the variable `$self`, not `$obj`

Comment: What if I want to access a method in another package(the parent)? Do I use $self or $obj? Like for example: `$obj->{parent}->testThree();`

Comment: IFAIK, allways use `$self`

Comment: `$self` is what `Method::Signatures` automatically provides instead of having to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions seem to indicate you do not understand the basics of scope, and how plain Perl objects work.

In Perl, when you use the `->method` syntax on a package name or blessed reference, the subroutine `method` in that package is invoked. The first argument to the subroutine is the thing on which you invoked `method`.

So, if you do

```
My::Friend->new('Alfred');
```

the `new` subroutine in the package `My::Friend` receives two arguments. `My::Friend` and `Alfred`.

In a new method, it is customary to refer to the first argument as `$class`, but that is completely up to you. You could use `$basket_case` if you were so inclined:

```
sub new {
   my $basket_case = shift;
   my $basket = shift;
   my $obj = bless { name => $basket } => $basket_case;
   return $obj;
}
```

If you then invoke a method on the returned reference, that method will receive said reference as its first argument, allowing you to access data stored in that reference:

```
sub blurb {
    my $schmorp = shift;
    print $schmorp->{name}, "\n";
    return;
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package My::Package;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $basket_case = shift;
    my $basket = shift;
    my $obj = bless { name => $basket } => $basket_case;
    return $obj;
}

sub blurb {
    my $schmorp = shift;
    print $schmorp->{name}, "\n";
    return;
}

sub derp {
    my $herp = shift;
    printf "%s derp derp\n", $herp->{name};
    return;
}

package main;

my $x = My::Package->new('Alfred');

$x->blurb;
$x->derp;
```

Output:

```
Alfred
Alfred derp derp
```

You need to understand these basics. Trying to put another layer of abstraction on top of the basics before understanding what is underneath will not make things any easier.

Now, if you are using `Method::Signatures`, it, by convention, puts that implicit first argument in a [lexically scoped](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) variable which, by default, it calls `$self`.

You can override that name in specific methods, and doing so in `new` might be a good idea to convey the fact that it doesn't expect an object instance; instead it returns a new instance.

Whatever you called that lexically scoped instance variable in one sub does not affect what it is called in another sub. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub a_number {
    my $number = int(rand(10));
    return $number;
}

sub square_that_number {
    my $x = shift;
    return $x * $x;
}

my $bzzzt = a_number();
my $trrrp = square_that_number($bzzzt);

print $trrrp, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./zt.pl
36
```

Comment: Like I said, I understand the non Method::Signatures way, Method::Signatures is something new to me and I'm having a bit of a tough time understaning how to use oo in it.

Comment: [Your code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521717/) demonstrated that you do not really understand the non `Method::Signatures` way. Also, if you understood scoping, you wouldn't think you would have to the instance variable as `$obj` in `testScript` just because you called it `$obj` in `new`. There is no shame in not understanding something. Indeed, Understanding what you don't understand is one of the most important factors determining whether you can learn something.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you need to backtrack a bit - you're `new` method is broken in the first place, which indicates that you don't really understand what's going on with OO perl.

A very simple object looks like this:

```
package Foo;

sub new {
    #when Foo -> new is called, then 'Foo' is passed in as the class name
    my ( $class ) = @_;
    #create an empty hash reference - can be anything, but $self is the convention
    my $self = {};
    #tell perl that $self is a 'Foo' object 
    bless ( $self, $class );
    #return the reference to your `Foo` object
    return $self;  
}

sub set_name {
   my ( $self, $new_name ) = @_;
   $self -> {name} = $new_name;
}

sub get_name {
   my ( $self ) = @_;
   return $self -> {name}; 
}
```

When you call this in your code:

```
use Foo;

my $new_instance = Foo -> new();
```

The class is passed into the `new` method, which you then use `bless` to create an instantiated object.

Then you can 'do stuff' with it - when you 'call' a method using `->` then the *first* argument into the subroutine is the object reference.

So

```
$new_instance -> set_name ( "myname" ); 
print $new_instance -> get_name();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Foo::set_name($new_instance, "myname" );
print Foo::get_name($new_instance);
```

You act on `$new_instance` which is a sort of magic hash that allows you to include code.

`Method::Signatures` is largely irrelevant until you understand the basics of OO. But what *that* does is 'simply' expand the functions within a module, such that you don't have to extract self/class etc.

By default, a method defined as `method` provides `$self` automatically. *no* `$obj` like you're using. That's a variable that's local to you `new` method, and simply doesn't exist outside that.